# How to get value from input box and store it in php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, http-post, concatenation

I'm working on this website and I can't seem to get some things to work.

I have 3 inputs in my html:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input id='counterName' name='counterName' type='text' value='nothing'></input>
</form>

<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='text' value='3' name='counterNum' class='counter'></input>
</form>

<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='Save' name='save' id='save'></input>
</form>
```

I want to get the value of the first two (counterName and counterNum) and store it in 2 variables when I click on the Save button. So I did:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $counterName = $_POST['counterName'];
        $counterNum = $_POST['counterNum'];
        $prefix = mysql_real_escape_string("`~");
}
```

You will see where $prefix is used in a second.

Next I want to take those three variables and save them to my MySql's database column by concatenating in the following format. "`~$counterName`~$counterNum". Here is how I did it:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `counter` = CONCAT (`counter`,'$prefix') WHERE `userID` = '$userID'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `counter` = CONCAT (`counter`,'$counterName') WHERE `userID` = '$userID'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `counter` = CONCAT (`counter`,'$prefix') WHERE `userID` = '$userID'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `counter` = CONCAT (`counter`,'$counterNum') WHERE `userID` = '$userID'");
```

My issue is that when I see what the column "counter" holds I see this: "`~`~" without the variables in between. What am I doing wrong? Btw the type of the column is VARCHAR.

Thank you.

Comment: why do u need separate form for each element?

Comment: Because the forms are inside different divs in my html code.

Comment: Add input elements in single form then work fine...

Comment: I did it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sadikhasan said in Comments, you should add inputs in a single form like this:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input id='counterName' name='counterName' type='text' value='nothing'></input>
    <input type='text' value='3' name='counterNum' class='counter'></input>
    <input type='submit' value='Save' name='save' id='save'></input>
</form>
```

this should solve your problem.

Comment: Just did it and still the same.

Comment: add enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to the form tag and try again

Comment: You are amazing! It worked. I've been trying to get it for so many hours. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Your welcome, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted